# Updating a variable inside a loop in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

Everytime I run this script, it prints 0 and then aborts with the error

```
./hw4_1: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `let'
./hw4_1: line 6: `  let COUNTER=0'
```

Source:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
echo $COUNTER
for i in {$@:2}do
  let COUNTER=0
  while [COUNTER -ne $1]; do
      echo "$i"
      let COUNTER+=1
    done;
done
exit
```

I've tried getting rid of let and adding a dollar sign before COUNTER, but no combination of those things work... This bash syntax is killing me.
Changing 'let COUNTER=0' to COUNTER=0
just returns the error

```
./hw4_1: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `let'  
./hw4_1: line 6: `  let COUNTER=0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a semicolon (or newline) after the value list in the for statement:

```
for i in "${@:2}"; do
```

I also added the quotes because you probably want them (but maybe not).

Comment: thanks for the help. For anyone who might read this, I also had to add spaces: [COUNTER -ne $1] to [ COUNTER -ne $1 ]

Comment: @Zach: Oh, yeah. I didn't notice that. In bash, a better version is `while ((COUNTER != $1)); do` (Unlike `[` and `{`, `(` is a self-delimiting character.

Comment: ...and I also messed up my attempt at array slicing ($ sign should be outside {})

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `let`.  Just use:

```
COUNTER=0
```

You will need $COUNTER elsewhere, for example:

```
while [ $COUNTER -ne $1 ]
```

and to do the increment:

```
COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))
```

Comment: It gives the error  './hw4_1: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `let'  
./hw4_1: line 6: `  let COUNTER=0''